How Do I Handle Backpressure When Combining Multiple Flux Streams Dynamically in Spring WebFlux?
I am working on a Spring WebFlux application and need to combine multiple Flux streams dynamically at runtime. These streams represent data from different sources, and the rate of data emission from each source is not predictable.
I want to process the combined data stream while ensuring proper backpressure handling to prevent memory overload or data loss if one of the sources emits data too quickly.
I have written the following code to merge the streams:
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

import java.time.Duration;

public class FluxMergeExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flux<String> stream1 = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(100))
                                   .map(i -> "Stream1-" + i)
                                   .take(10);

        Flux<String> stream2 = Flux.interval(Duration.ofMillis(300))
                                   .map(i -> "Stream2-" + i)
                                   .take(10);

        Flux<String> combinedStream = Flux.merge(stream1, stream2);

        combinedStream.subscribe(System.out::println);
    }
}


This works fine for the given example, but I have the following questions:

Dynamic Stream Addition: In my actual use case, the streams are not known at compile time. How can I dynamically add new streams to the Flux at runtime?

Backpressure: When one of the streams emits data at a much faster rate than the others, how can I ensure backpressure is handled appropriately? Would switching to Flux.combineLatest() or Flux.concat() be a better approach, and why?

Error Handling: If one of the streams encounters an error, I want to log it and continue processing the other streams. What is the best way to achieve this?


What I’ve Tried:

I experimented with Flux.concat(), but it processes the streams sequentially, which is not suitable for my use case.

Using Flux.zip() requires all streams to emit data simultaneously, which leads to unnecessary waiting.

I’ve read about Schedulers in Reactor but am unsure how to use them effectively here.


Goal:

To be able to dynamically add streams at runtime.
To ensure proper backpressure handling regardless of emission rates.
To gracefully handle errors in individual streams without stopping the entire pipeline.

Any Guidance would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

To be able to dynamically add streams at runtime. you would need to supply a code example here as far as you can get as this is not clear.
